# Can't extract data from the result of json_decode php

Tags: php, html, json

This is the result of json_decode&echo I recieve, but I cant build a list/table of it. Everything I've found on the topic so far didnt work out for me, maybe its because of complicated nesting. I would apprecieate any help, just point me in the right direction, no need to make all the work for me. Thanks in advance!

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
        (
            [Element] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1001
                    [name] => Element 1
                )

        )

    [1002] => Array
        (
            [Element] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1002
                    [name] => Element 2
                )

        )

    [1003] => Array
        (
            [Element] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1003
                    [name] => Element 3
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: use `foreach` for get json data one by one. here must use nested `foreach` loop for get results data and save it.

Answer (score 1):

Try foreach

```
 foreach ( $your_json_array as $key=>$value){
       foreach($value as $ele=>$elearray){
            echo $elearray['id'];
            echo $elearray['name']; 
      }
    }
```